# Remove [h264 @ xxx] error cosole output while using cv2

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, h.264, dji-sdk

I'm using the djitellopy module (running on Win10/Python3.6) to connect to my Ryze TELLO-drone. That module uses cv2, the drone provides the current the videostream in h264 codec. While running my script (based on [the docs](https://github.com/damiafuentes/DJITelloPy/blob/master/example.py)), not all pictures are getting transmitted e. g. because my wlan connection is too weak. That's not the actual problem, as I don't need all 60fps. But it's quite annoying, that every time I miss a frame, I get errors like

```
[h264 @ 0000019ab6699b40] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000019ab6699b40] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000019ab6699b40] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000019ab8394b00] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000019ab66ab040] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0000019ab8394b00] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0000019ab8394b00] no frame!
[h264 @ 0000019ab8394b00] error while decoding MB 31 40, bytestream -10
```

and so on. Is there any neat way to turn off/suppress these errors in cv2? The script itself is running on without problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an ffmpeg error. Does your library allow you to change the log level? If not, you could just redirect all stderr to /dev/null

Comment: I tried `
import sys
log = []
class writer(object):
    def write(self, data): log.append(data)
sys.stderr = writer()
`, but nothing has changed. The lib itself is not logging at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, but I decided to simply ignore the outputs by using a tkinter-windows to diplay data instead of the commandline. Case closed.